# How to create a "danger" button in fluentui (office ui fabric)?

Tags: office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

How to create a "danger" (red) button in the Microsoft fluentui library?
Like one have in other ui frameworks like bootstrap etc.

There are `<DefaultButton>` and `<PrimaryButton>` but I have not found anything like `<DangerButton>`?

Alternatively, how do you specify the style in such a way so that button uses the "danger" color specified by the theme?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `button style` from the following *DefaultButton Component properties*: *Style, Styles, Class Name, Theme*.

Property `style` of *DefaultButton Component*:

```js
<DefaultButton style={{ backgroundColor: '#f00' }} />
```

Property `styles` of *DefaultButton Component*:

```js
<DefaultButton
  styles={{
    root: {
      backgroundColor: '#f00',
      color: '#fff',
    }        
  }}
/>
```

Property `className` of *DefaultButton Component*:

```js
// CSS 
.btn-danger { background-color: #f00; }

// Component
<DefaultButton className="btn-danger" />
```

Property `theme` of *DefaultButton Component*:

```js
import { createTheme, DefaultButton, ITheme } from 'office-ui-fabric-react'

...

const dangerButtonTheme: ITheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    white: '#f00',
    neutralPrimary: '#fff',
  },
})

<DefaultButton theme={dangerButtonTheme} />
```

Codepen [working example](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/oNLBmQL?editors=0110)

Useful links:

- [Component Styling](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/wiki/Component-Styling)
- Base Button [styles definition](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/cbc0b9a2f9b569eeabd7bba3812002edcca948e8/packages/react-internal/src/components/Button/BaseButton.styles.ts)
- [Theme Designer](https://fabricweb.z5.web.core.windows.net/pr-deploy-site/refs/heads/7.0/theming-designer/index.html)

Comment: Sorry I did not mention properly I guess, I want to use existing theme (I'm creating a SharePoint extension, so all colors are already sort of predefined by the SharePoint theme). I don't want to overwrite them or create my custom color theme.

Comment: I'm trying to understand, you want to apply a color from existing theme to Button component right? https://github.com/callstack/react-theme-provider/blob/master/README.md#usage

Comment: I'm building SPFx SharePoint extension using the fluentui library. And wuold like to add a "danger" button that would have the same style SharePoint does basically. Please note that the theme colors are selected by SharePoint, not by me.

Comment: Please note that some FluentUI components accept function as a parameter for "styles". But the "Button" requires a constant, not a function as a value for "styles"

Answer (score 1):

There is no "danger" button type in fluent ui, you will have to style it yourself.

See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/wiki/Component-Styling#object-based-styling) an example (you also can basically just add a className to the button and style it however you like).

Comment: This is what I suspected... How do I use theme color to style the button as "danger"? The styles prop for a button is not a function but a constant. Am I supposed to hardcode the colors?